# In react-router v4, can we still do `this.props.children` in the App container?

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4

In react-router v2, we can do

```
// inside of routes.js

export default (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={PostsIndex} />
    <Route path="/posts/new" component={PostsNew} />
    <Route path="/posts/:id" component={PostsShow} />
  </Route>
);
```

and then show the proper child inside of the App container:

```
// inside app.js

{this.props.children}
```

but in react-router v4, `{this.props.children}` doesn't work any more. Is it done another way?

Answer (score 0):

V4 is a major update and is a complete re-write of <=V3. You shouldn't expect to upgrade to V4 and have everything work still. I recommend checking out the [documentation examples](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) so you can see how things work. Here's a basic example which demonstrates nested routes like you have.

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom'

const BasicExample = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/topics">Topics</Link></li>
      </ul>

      <hr/>

      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
      <Route path="/topics" component={Topics}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
)

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Home</h2>
  </div>
)

const About = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>About</h2>
  </div>
)

const Topics = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Topics</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/rendering`}>
          Rendering with React
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/components`}>
          Components
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/props-v-state`}>
          Props v. State
        </Link>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <Route path={`${match.url}/:topicId`} component={Topic}/>
    <Route exact path={match.url} render={() => (
      <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>
    )}/>
  </div>
)

const Topic = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>{match.params.topicId}</h3>
  </div>
)

export default BasicExample
```

Comment: So you are saying No you can't. which means one of the most popular features is now broken. Plus this answer, answers a different question than what was asked this answer is about nest routes when the question was about this.props.children ie nested props. This answer could have been a lot shorter " Uh Maybe- and go read the docs" was all that was added by this answer.

Comment: @BoxandCox I read your comment 3 times and I'm still unsure of what you're actually trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it took a few hours until i found the solution

```
 const PageNavWithChildrenComponentInsideLayout = ({ match }) => {

      return <div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <NavLink className="nav-link" to={"/consultant/childOne"} activeClassName={`${match.url}/childOne` ? "active": ""}>
              </NavLink>
               <NavLink className="nav-link" to={"/consultant/childTwo"} activeClassName={`${match.url}/childTwo` ? "active": ""}>
              </NavLink>
               <NavLink className="nav-link" to={"/consultant/childThree"} activeClassName={`${match.url}/childThree` ? "active": ""}>
              </NavLink>
            </li>
          </ul>

          {/**
            Layout is Wrapper component corresponds parent v2,v3
          **/}

         <Layout>

          {/**corresponds {this.props.children}**/}

           <Route exact path={`${match.url}/childOne`} component={ChildOne}/>
           <Route exact path={`${match.url}/childTwo`} component={ChildTwo}/>
           <Route exact path={`${match.url}/childThree`} component={ChildThree}/>

          </Layout>

        </div>;
    };

    export default PageNavWithChildrenComponentInsideLayout 

    {/**-------------Routes.js--------------*/}


    export default routes=()=>{

    <Switch>
     <Route path="/PageNavWithChildrenComponentInsideLayout" name="Parent" component={PageNavWithChildrenComponentInside}>
      <Route path="/PageNavWithChildrenComponentInsideLayout/childOne" name="ChildOne" component={ChildOne} />
      <Route path="/PageNavWithChildrenComponentInsideLayout/childTwo" name="ChildTwo" component={ChildTwo} />
      <Route path="/PageNavWithChildrenComponentInsideLayout/childThree" name="ChildThree" component={ChildThree} />
     </Route>
    </Switch>
    }
```

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code. Paste the code, select it, press Ctrl-K to get it formatted.